# sed: bad option in substitution expression when trying to replace a string

Tags: bash, unix, sed, terraform

tr file and trying to change data in it and getting this substitution error.

**my file data is**

```
variable "aws_spoke_gateways" {
  default = {
    spoke1 = {
      name         = "AWS-UE2-Spoke1-GW"
    },
    spoke2 = {
      name         = "AWS-UE2-Spoke1-GW"
    }
  }
}
```

**And My desired output is**

```
 variable "aws_spoke_gateways" {
      default = {
        spoke1 = {
          name         = "myname"
        },
        spoke2 = {
          name         = "AWS-UE2-Spoke1-GW"
        }
      }
    }
```

**EDIT 1**

I want to change the values of name , size , and vpc  and both `spoke1` and `spoke2`

```
variable "aws_spoke_gateways" {
  default = {
    spoke1 = {
      name         = "AZ-EU-Spoke1-GW"
      size         = "Standard_B1ms"
      active_mesh  = true
      single_az_ha = true
      vpc          = "azure_spoke2_vnet"
    },
    spoke2 = {
      name         = "AZ-EU-Spoke2-GW"
      size         = "Standard_B1ms"
      active_mesh  = true
      single_az_ha = true
      vpc          = "azure_spoke2_vnet"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your input is spread over multiple lines, `sed` will only process one line at a time.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for comment sir , In this case what I can do then ?

Comment: Use some other tool, like `awk`, that allows you to keep state in variables.

Comment: Also, I recommend using single quotes around the sed argument, so you don't have to escape the double quotes inside it.

Comment: @Barmar sir kindly can you please give example for this scenario .

Comment: I'm not going to write it for you.

Comment: Why don't you do it similarly to the solution I gave you yesterday, where you use a range of line?

Comment: And substitute between them.

Comment: Also, it looks like your pattern doesn't match the `"` around `AWS-UE2-SPOKE1-GW` and doesn't put `"` around `myname`

Comment: @Barmar  yes sir I am following that last day answer , that worked for that particular attribute but this name thing is not changing

Comment: You don't have `/start/,/end/` in this command. You also have `s` at the beginning, which was the first mistake I pointed out yesterday.

Comment: It seems like you're having trouble understanding the general principles of `sed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ranges to make sure you get the right one. Here's a quick example you can refine -

```
$: sed '/spoke1/,/\},/ { s/AWS-UE2-Spoke1-GW/myname/; }' file
variable "aws_spoke_gateways" {
  default = {
    spoke1 = {
      name         = "myname"
    },
    spoke2 = {
      name         = "AWS-UE2-Spoke1-GW"
    }
  }
}
```

If you need more granular control, you can nest the ranges.

```
$: sed '/variable "aws_spoke_gateways" \{/,/^\},/ {
     /spoke1/,/\},/ { s/AWS-UE2-Spoke1-GW/new1/; }
     /spoke2/,/\},/ { s/AWS-UE2-Spoke1-GW/new2/; }
}' file
variable "aws_spoke_gateways" {
  default = {
    spoke1 = {
      name         = "new1"
    },
    spoke2 = {
      name         = "new2"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I added an anchor on the ending brace of the outer wrapper: `^\},`

The manual is your friend. Read it all the way through once, you'll save enough hours to make up for it.

- https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Comment: neat and clean solution.

Comment: kindly change to previous one . that was good

Comment: `sed -i '/variable "aws_spoke_gateways" [{]/,/[}],/ { s/AWS-UE2-Spoke1-GW/myname/; }' `   working perfect . just wanted to ask if I want to change `spoke2`  attribute  `name` using this same command how I will ?

Comment: I edited the condition set - take another look. It's currently scanning `/spoke1/,/\},/`. Just change that to `/spoke2/,/\},/`, should do it.

Answer (score 3):

Consume the file as one line using sed -z and so:

```
 sed -Ezi 's/(^.*spoke1 = .*= ")(.*)(".*\},.*$)/\1myname\3/' file
```

Enable extended regular expressions with -E. Split the file into 3 sections based on regular expression. Print the first section followed by the changed name (myname in this case), then the 3rd section.

Modified solution after further comments from OP:

Original data:

```
variable "aws_spoke_gateways" {
  default = {
    spoke1 = {
      name         = "AWS-UE2-Spoke1-GW"
    },
    spoke2 = {
      name         = "AWS-UE2-Spoke2-GW"
    },
    spoke3 = {
      name         = "AWS-UE2-Spoke3-GW"
    },
    spoke4 = {
      name         = "AWS-UE2-Spoke4-GW"
    }

 }
}


spoke1="test1"
spoke2="test2"
spoke3="test3"
spoke4="test4"

sed -Ez "s/(^.*spoke1 = .*= \")(.*)(\".*\},.*spoke2.*$)/\1$spoke1\3/;s/(^.*spoke2 = .*= \")(.*)(\".*\},.*spoke3.*$)/\1$spoke2\3/;s/(^.*spoke3 = .*= \")(.*)(\".*\},.*$)/\1$spoke3\3/;s/(^.*spoke4 = .*= \")(.*)(\".*\}.*$)/\1$spoke4\3/" file
```

Result:

```
variable "aws_spoke_gateways" {
 default = {
   spoke1 = {
     name         = "test1"
   },
   spoke2 = {
     name         = "test2"
   },
   spoke3 = {
     name         = "test3"
   },
   spoke4 = {
     name         = "test4"
   }

 }
}
```

Comment: **getting this error :**   sed: -e expression #1, char 49: unterminated `s' command

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the last / Should work now.

Comment: Sir , working but I need to make a generic solution . I have posted a another question. can you please look that ?

Comment: Generic how?, If you put the sed statement in quotes, you can specify the text to search for as a variable ie var and the text to change as a variable also i.e. var1  i.e. "s/(^.*$var = .*= ")(.*)(".*\},.*$)/\1$var1\3/'

Comment: No I mean , Its replacing name variable mean last one in `spoke`  I have another values as well to be changed , then where I have to make change ?

Comment: So you want to change every entry for spoke at once to the same name?

Comment: No idea is like , there are 4 entries of spoke and user will enter all , I will get data from user and replace here :(

Comment: OK, check out the amendment. I think it may be what you are after

Comment: I am sorry I think I could not convey properly. I am saying I will have  many variables in spoke1  :  name , vpc , ccl , duration   .  I need to change those :(

Comment: You need to update the original question then with all the variables you need to change

Comment: Sir I made a EDIT , kindly have a look .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225833/discussion-between-raman-sailopal-and-shahroz-pervaz).

Answer (score 1):

Given the new requirements, it seem that awk would be a better approach than sed:

Set the variables before proceeding

```
spke="spoke1" # The spoke we are concerned with
var="size" # The variable within the spoke section we are concerned with
val="size1" # The value we want to change to.
```

Pass these variable into GNU awk with -v

```
awk -v spke="$spke" -v var="$var" -v val="$val" '
      /spoke[[:digit:]][[:space:]]=/ { 
                                        spoke=$1 # Track the spoke section
                                     } 
          spoke==spke && $1==var { # If spoke is equal to the passed spoke and the first space separated field is equal to the variable we want to change (var), process
                                        $0=gensub(/(^.*=[[:space:]]")(.*)(".*$)/,"\\1"val"\\3",$0) # Substitute the value for the value passed (val)
                                     }1' file
```

One liner

```
awk -v spke="$spke" -v var="$var" -v val="$val" '/spoke[[:digit:]][[:space:]]=/ { spoke=$1 } spoke==spke && $1==var { $0=gensub(/(^.*=[[:space:]]")(.*)(".*$)/,"\\1"val"\\3",$0) }1' file
```

If you have a recent version of GNU awk, you can commit the changes to the file by simply adding the -i flag and so:

```
awk -i -v spke="$spke" -v var="$var" -v val="$val" '/spoke[[:digit:]][[:space:]]=/ { spoke=$1 } spoke==spke && $1==var { $0=gensub(/(^.*=[[:space:]]")(.*)(".*$)/,"\\1"val"\\3",$0) }1' file
```

Otherwise:

```
awk -v spke="$spke" -v var="$var" -v val="$val" '/spoke[[:digit:]][[:space:]]=/ { spoke=$1 } spoke=="spoke1" && $1==var { $0=gensub(/(^.*=[[:space:]]")(.*)(".*$)/,"\\1"val"\\3",$0) }1' file > file.tmp && mv -f file.tmp file
```